# how to run a script on ubuntu shutdown when it needs network on

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have an upstart script that needs to run on reboot or shutdown, but it needs to access the network to post an http requests and wait for the replies, I tried

```
start on starting rc
```

and

```
start on starting (rc and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
```

but no luck.

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/117584/upstart-scripts-run-a-task-after-networking-goes-up. Another option is to use `start on net-device-up` instead of specifying specific interface. As it is possible that the interface is not really responsible for network connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the following job contents:

```
# The deconfiguring-networking bit stops the network from going down until we are done here.
start on runlevel [016] or deconfiguring-networking

task

exec /path/to/myscript.sh
```